# Add multiple GridLayouts inside of a GridLayout kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to be able to dynamically add GridLayouts to a single GridLayout container.

my code:

```
layout = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint= (None,None))
...
get_score = data.get(key, {}).get('score')
                can = self.root.get_screen("three")

                for x in range(-1, get_score): # had to use -1 to get correct amount of shapes
                    can.ids.my_box.add_widget(layout)
```

kv:

```
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: my_box
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 50
```

When I try doing this I get error

```
 kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0x00000274FEFD9B40>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0x00000274FEFD99A0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add the same widget (a GridLayout named `layout`) multiple times in your loop. Try putting the `layout = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint= (None,None))` line inside the for loop, then it'll be a different widget each time and your code should run.